# Packaging approach for SharePoint 2010 template

Tags: sharepoint, templates, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I have a SharePoint 2010 template which is using a farm deployed solution. What could be the best approach to provide this site template to the client. Should I create just one wsp for the site and it will include the farm deployed solution automatically or will I have to give two wsp's to my client, one for the farm solution and one for the site?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to go with 2 wsp. its not good idea to deploy functionality which is not required.

create 1 wsp for farm level 
and second for Site collection level deployment